# Objective-C inheritance

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I'm making a very simple app that has lots of different quizzes. My motivation is primarily to learn Objective-C and iOS development. So I have a few views in my app, all of them have the same background which I set programmatically. I decided to make a subclass of `UIViewController` which added the function `setBackground`, and make all ViewControllers in my app inherit this subclass (`SumsViewController`).

This worked fine, but now I'd like to take out some of the stuff that's common to each quiz and add that in to a subclass of `SumsViewController`, called `QuizController`. Having tried this I'm getting errors about `property x not found on object of type y`.

Here's the code:

**SumsViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SumsViewController : UIViewController
- (void)setBackground;
@end
```

**SumsViewController.m**

```
#import "SumsViewController.h"

@interface SumsViewController ()

@end

@implementation SumsViewController

- (void)setBackground
{
    ... //Code to set Background
}

@end
```

**QuizController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SumsViewController.h"

@interface QuizController : SumsViewController

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger number1;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger number2;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger difficulty;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger score_val;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimer* countdown;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger time_val;

@end
```

**QuizController.m**

```
#import "QuizController.h"

@interface QuizController ()

@end

@implementation QuizController

@end
```

Now here's a controller for a quiz that inherits QuizController:

**AdditionController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "QuizController.h"

@interface AdditionController : QuizController

@end
```

**AdditionController.m**

```
#import "AdditionController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface AdditionController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *question;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *ans1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *ans2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *ans3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *score;
@end

@implementation AdditionController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   [self setBackground]; //function declared in SumsViewController WORKS FINE
   self.difficulty = 20; //declared in QuizController DOES NOT WORK
   // Error says property not member of object AdditionController

   [self setupGame];
}
@end
```

I'd appreciate any help on this, I'm sure it's a simple misunderstanding but this is frustrating me.

Comment: I also noticed your `NSTimer` is not defined as `strong` which is almost definitely a mistake. It should probably be `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer* countdown;`

Comment: Yeah that was a typo when I copied it over, it is defined as `strong` in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cleaning you project and re building files ( Command + Shift + K ).
I'm suggesting that because I just copied your code in a sample project, and it works fine on my computer.